# How to enter an iceberg order on an online brokerage web platform

Tags: limit-order, market-order

On my order entry screen (my broker is questrade), I see a field called 'Iceberg'.I looked up 'Iceberg' and apparently it is some kind of mechanism to hide large orders by breaking it into parts. What value should I enter into the 'Iceberg' field? is it the % of the order volume that I want to display openly? How will the rest of the order be taken care of?

I asked all this to my broker, he does not know.

Comment: http://help.questrade.com/how-to/iq-web/placing-an-order/creating-a-stock-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "iceberg" or normally "tip" field is how much of the order you want displayed at any given time.  The rest will be held in reserve to be posted after either part or the entire tip has been filled.

Brokerages can structure the commissions due to this order in any number of ways.  There could be a fee for each fill making it expensive, or there could be only a fee per share making it cheap.

It should be noted that this order is prone to slippage and is unnecessary if the order is less than or equal to the size of the best opposing order.

Comment: -1 How does that answer the question in any way ?? He probably has googled what an iceberg order means and wants to know how to use it on his trading platform.

Comment: @DumbCoder "What value should I enter into the 'Iceberg' field? is it the % of the order volume that I want to display openly?" indicates to me that he is unaware that that field is the maximum portion in the market which I addressed.  "How will the rest of the order be taken care of?" indicates that he doesn't know how the rest of the order will be taken care of which I addressed.  I gave him a little extra to get him on his way.  This is a "punk'd" episode, right?

Comment: Thanks both of you. So each time a portion of the order gets executed, I pay a commission?

Comment: @Kaushik I could not find your broker's fee schedule, but I did edit to give some scenarios.